# 4-column layout in CSS Flexbox is wrapping into a new line on very small screens?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.box-1 {
  background: #581f18;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #f0a202;
}
.box-3 {
  background: #d95d39;
}
.box-4 {
  background: #202c59;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <!-- children = flex-items -->
      <div class="box box-1">1</div>
      <div class="box box-2">2</div>
      <div class="box box-3">3</div>
      <div class="box box-4">4</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to set up a 4-column layout using CSS Flexbox.  I  `flex: 0 0 25%;`, `box-sizing:border-box;` and `padding:30px;`

Everything works fine on larger screens but when I try to see this on smaller screens my 4th column wraps up to next line. This is happening because of left and right padding because when I set it as 0 everything works fine.

4-column layout is respected on every screen. I want to know the reason why this happening.

[With left and right paddng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vOSG.png)

[Without left and right padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVAjR.png)

I tried to set box-sizing as border box so it can respect left and right padding even on smaller screens but for some reason it doesn't. Could someone please tell me why?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: If you add 30px padding on every box, it will overflow. What do you expect to happen? Just the padding on the four boxes will take up 240px; plus the width of the text, 20-30px each.

Comment: but it works fine with 27px as padding. I want to know what is the limit so I can decide if I want to keep padding or not in future projects. What is the min value of CSS flexbox item from which it can't be shrinked below and if we try it'll overflow.

Comment: It just means that the four text widths plus the eight 27px padding and the two 5px border is less than or equal to the available width. E.g. if you check it in a 320px viewport width, the text is 23px wide, and you choose 27px padding, then the four boxes plus the red border will be `8*27px + 4*23px + 2*5px = 318px`, so it fits. If you increase the padding to 35px, the same would be `8*35px + 4*23px + 2*5px = 382px`. As it's larger than the 320px, the last box will drop to the next line because you added `flex-wrap` on the parent.

Comment: so it depends on how much width is available and text-width that it will fit or not. Thank you so much for the answer. Could you give me one advice, in general should I use left and right padding in flexbox?

Answer (score -2):

flex-wrap property wraps the columns to a new line if its columns don't get enough space to fit in.

To Change this behavior update your container style like this -

```
 .container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
.container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.box {
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #f3f3f3;
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
.box-1 {
  background: #581f18;
}
.box-2 {
  background: #f0a202;
}
.box-3 {
  background: #d95d39;
}
.box-4 {
  background: #202c59;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <!-- children = flex-items -->
      <div class="box box-1">1</div>
      <div class="box box-2">2</div>
      <div class="box box-3">3</div>
      <div class="box box-4">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work. now my 4th box is overflowing

Comment: @NikhilKumar Yes, that will overflow in small screen because each box has fixed 35px font-size and some fixed horizontal padding (if you add) as well

Comment: but it won't overflow if I set left and right padding as 0. Technically it still taking 25%

Comment: @NikhilKumar Try to minimize the screen further, it'll overflow.

Comment: it didn't i tried 500x zoom on normal screen. It will when it becomes very very small. When we try to decrease it further 22.5px(width)

Comment: So, now your question solved?

Comment: Your welcome,If it solved by my answer then you can mark my answer as accepted answer.